# How can I use the draw navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I' creating a app for my Startup and I need to use a stack and a draw navigator, I already developed all the stack but the draw just dont appears
check my code

```
 import React from 'react';
 import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
 import{ View, ScrollView, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
 import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
 import {createStackNavigator}  from '@react-navigation/stack' 
 import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer'
 import { render } from 'react-dom';
 import  Home from './screens/Mainpage'
 import  Dermatologistas from './screens/Dermatologistas'
 import  Hospitais from './screens/Hospitais'


 import * as firebase from 'firebase'
 import { firebaseConfig } from './firebaseconfig';
 import react from 'react';
 import Login from './screens/Login';
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)






  const  width = Dimensions.get('window').width
  const heigth = Dimensions.get('window').height
```

here I created a Stack const and Drawer const

```
 const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()
 const Stack = createStackNavigator()
```

here I made the draw function

```
 function Draw() {
   return(
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator> 

   );
 }
```

here I export the app

```
  export default function App(){
     return (
  
       <NavigationContainer initialRouteName="Home">
           <Stack.Navigator>
      
           <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
           <Stack.Screen name="Dermatologistas" component={Dermatologistas}/>
           <Stack.Screen name="Hospitais" component={Hospitais}/>
           <Stack.Screen name="Draw" component={Draw}/>
      
         </Stack.Navigator>
   
       </NavigationContainer>
      
      );
     }
```

Comment: you want the drawer in all screens or just in Home and Login ?

Comment: In all the screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do is

```
renderHomeNavigator = () => {

    <Stack.Navigator>
      
           <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
           <Stack.Screen name="Dermatologistas" component={Dermatologistas}/>
           <Stack.Screen name="Hospitais" component={Hospitais}/>      
    </Stack.Navigator>
}



<NavigationContainer>

    <Stack.Navigator>

            <Drawer.Navigator>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={this.renderHomeNavigator}/>
            </Drawer.Navigator> 

            <Stack.Screen
              name="Login"
              component={Login}
            />
   </Stack.Navigator>          
   

</NavigationContainer>
```